# In an ANN layer, do units always work independently from each other?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

In a neural network layer, do units always work independently from each other? More generally, I am looking for the definition of a layer. Can any set of units be declared as forming a layer?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which type of ANN you are using. In a hidden layer, if you don't have direct any connections between each of the hidden neurons then each neuron will be independent of each other.

For example for an 'unrestricted' Boltzmann Machine has connections between hidden units so they will not be independent while a multilayer perceptron has neurons in hidden layer which are independent of other layer hidden neurons (of the same layer).

You cannot have any set of neurons being called a layer. Whether units form a layer depends on the units from which they draw their inputs. If your units gets input direct from the input layer, these units will form the '1st hidden' layer.  All neurons which draw input from '1st hidden layer neurons' will form 2nd hidden layer and so on.